# Derivation of minimum uncertainty from Squeezed Coherent State

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I'm studying a book in which I stopped by this point. I don't know how to derive the inequality from 
$$tr(\rho A^{*}A )?$$

[image: Book-29]

Comment: It probably would be best if you copied the relevant portion of the document into the body, rather than having us download the PDF. Not also that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5968/25301) on explicit derivations.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know. I will put pdf in body asap. This is my research materials, not HW :D

Comment: I think you can figure it out with a hint or two.

For any operator $M$ the expectation value of the operator is:
$\langle M \rangle = Tr[\rho M]$

The commutation relation between canonical position and momentum operators, if we set $\hbar=1$, is $ [Q_0 ,P_0]=i$

Comment: Thanks dudes. I got it. Actually I was stupid, was trying to reach it by vacuum state. Now I'm able to derive that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $\rho$ is the density matrix for a pure state, but it's nonetheless a density matrix (simply one with von Neumann entropy of nought, but that doesn't matter).

Recall that for any Hermitian operator $\hat{M}$, the $n^{th}$ moment of the probability distribution of the measurement made by $\hat{M}$ is $\mathrm{tr}(\rho\,\hat{M}^n)$. See, for example, the Wikipedia Page on the density matrix for further information.

Here $n=1$ and we're simply calculating the mean of the Hermitian operator $A^\dagger\,A$.

But the state is pure, so $\mathrm{tr}(\rho\,\hat{M}^n)$ is the same as $\langle\psi|A^\dagger\,A|\psi\rangle$.

1. Prove to yourself that $A^\dagger\,A$ is Hermitian, thus justifying the above;
2. What can you say about the eigenvalues of $A^\dagger\,A$? (they are the same as the singular values of $A$ on its own)?
3. What then can you say about the mean represented by $\langle\psi|A^\dagger\,A|\psi\rangle$?